# why is my CSV file partially indexed and how can I query it via haystack and Solr admin

Tags: solr

I indexed my CSV file using HTTP-POST as per tutorials.

The 100 000 row CSV file seems to be partially indexed (46339). When I go to "schema browser" in the Solr admin, I can see that numDocs : 1, maxDoc=46339. And in the fields section I can see all that partially indexed info.

Problem is I can't query it in app with Haystack, neither can I query it in the Solr admin. Only the *:* query works and it returns only ONE result. All other queries return a 'NumFound="0" start="0"'

How can I index my full file and be able to query from the Solr admin and haystack?

Answer (score 0):

try with a smaller file first, there is probably some invalid char in your cvs that makies Solr create an invalid index.

Answer (score 0):

What do the server logs say? I suspect you might be trying to index too large a file all at once. Try doing it as multiple indexing requests.

Also make sure that the content was committed. I believe post tool should print that out as a message.